# passing bash expression to AWK for floating point arithmetic

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I was trying to do floating point arithmetic in bash, but as floats are not supported, was trying to get the solution using AWK. Below is the issue i am facing:

I see this working fine for me:

**code**

```
echo - | awk '{printf("%04.4f \n", (-225.2*7+30*6)/17 + (19^2)/9) }'
```

**output**

> -42.0301

But my motive is to "**read an expression**" and compute value correct to 4 decimals, so tried below code inputting same expression (-225.2*7+30*6)/17 + (19^2)/9) and its giving incorrect values(i guess variable is passed as string to awk):

**code**

```
read inpt 
echo - | awk -v input=$inpt '{printf("%04.4f \n", input) }'
```

**output**

> 0.0000

Note: Please ignore the space around second + in this example expression, that i can remove using sed or similar methods(with space i get syntactical error in awk while passing variable from bash).

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

PS: the bash version in my case is "bash-4.2". I guess its the version of bash preventing me using from many other options.

Comment: The Bash version doesn't affect the availability of external commands. Getting access to `bc` may be a simple matter of `sudo apt install -y bc` or the equivalent for your platform.

Answer (score 4):

You can't evaluate data in a variable in awk out of the box. In this case you need to write an arithmetic evaluator or use a pre-existing one, like https://github.com/radare/radare2-bindings/blob/master/awk/calc.awk . Once you fix that missing parenthesis and quote your expression properly, you can:

```
$ echo "((-225.2*7+30*6)/17 + (19^2)/9)" | awk -f calc.awk
((-225.2*7+30*6)/17 + (19^2)/9) =        -42.0301
```

Comment: or you can simply pipe it to `bc`, while setting the required scale.

Comment: In an another answer's comments that was already deleted OP mentioned that he cannot use the `bc`.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend and have upvoted James Brown's answer. But if you need something here and now with no external dependencies, you can simply interpolate the input into the script.

```
awk "END { printf("%04.4f\n", $input) }" </dev/null
```

This is functionally equivalent to using `eval` so if this isn't deployed where you know you can trust the input (e.g. because it comes from a controlled process, not an actual user) you will need to perform some sort of sanitization (and even then probably cope with odd or outright misleading error messages if the input isn't a well-formed Awk expression).

```
read -p "Input an Awk expression: " input
case $input in
  *[!-+/*()^%0-9]*)
    echo "$0: invalid input" >&2
    exit 1;;
esac
awk ...
```

Notice also the construct to avoid the basically useless `echo`. Redirecting input from `/dev/null` and putting your code in the `END` (or `BEGIN`) block is a standard technique for running an arbitrary piece of Awk script without requiring any input.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't see anything wrong in the command, it should work. Please try again the exact commands posted and provide exact details if the issue persists.

However, if all you need is formating the output, you can do it directly with `printf`.

```
$ read input
12.34
$ printf '%4.4f' $input
12.3400
```

EDIT:

If you need to format the output after performing some calculation, then you can alternatively use `bc`. (`awk` should still work)

```
$ echo "scale=4; (-225.2*7+30*6)/17+(19^2)/9" | bc
-42.0300
```

You can use variables in the expression as usual,

```
$ read inpt
1234
$ echo "scale=4; $inpt * 0.01" | bc
12.34
```

Comment: i actually need to evaluate the expression not merely print a floating number, which i dont see working in regular bash script. Its working in awk but am not able to pass floating expression variable from bash to awk construct

Comment: well, I I said I don't see anything wrong in what you have tried. However since I'm also (as in the other answer) a fan of bc, I would do some thing like following `echo "scale=4; (-225.2*7+30*6)/17+(19^2)/9" | bc` or using `read` input  `echo "scale=4; $inpt * 12.34" | bc`

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
 echo "25 50"| awk '{print $2,"/",$1}' | bc
```